# Uncaught error: invalid instruction; RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length

Tags: web3.js

I use https://docs.solana.com/developing/lookup-tables An error will be reported when Fetch an Address Lookup Table method is used. Uncaught error: invalid instruction;  RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length.
Can you help me out?
Code block:
const lookupTableAddress = new web3.PublicKey(
"BNhLBVM7rCxCShds7wVgYCqpTZBJnPNsd8gMhc6gGv3g"
);
console.log("lookupTableAddress-publicKey:", lookupTableAddress.toBase58());
// get the table from the cluster
const lookupTableAccount = await connection
.getAddressLookupTable(lookupTableAddress)
.then((res) => res.value);
// lookupTableAccount will now be a AddressLookupTableAccount object
console.log("Table address from cluster:", lookupTableAccount);

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this account only exists on devnet: https://explorer.solana.com/address/BNhLBVM7rCxCShds7wVgYCqpTZBJnPNsd8gMhc6gGv3g?cluster=devnet, but it has 0 allocated length and is not assigned to the Address Lookup Table program, which means that it isn't even a lookup table.  Perhaps there's a different address that you should be using? You pretty much just need to create the lookup table, then fetching it should work.